# Does smoothing divergent series with cutoff functions give consistent results?

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, reference-request, divergent-series

One way to try to give a value $S$ to a divergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is with a smooth cutoff function:
$$
S = \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \eta\left(\frac{n}{N}\right)
$$
where $\eta(0)=1$, and $\eta$ has some smoothness conditions (e.g. $C^2$ or $C^\infty$...) and some asymptotic decay conditions (e.g. $\eta$ is compactly supported or decays exponentially...).

Coming from a physics background, this seems one of the most natural approaches to take. And barring some small caveats it nicely encapsulates other approaches like Abel summation ($\eta(x) = e^{-x}$) and Cesaro summation ($\eta(x) = (1-x)_+$). But surprisingly, there seems a massive dearth of mathematical literature about this general class of approaches. (In particular, I've skimmed Hardy's Divergent Series and didn't spot anything about it.) In fact, Terry Tao's [classic blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/) on the subject seems to be almost the sole reference! One obvious question is simply: are there any good discussions of this family of approaches out there?

However, the question I'm most interested in is: are there any nice **consistency results** about these approaches? For example, is the following statement true (potentially with some conditions on $\eta$ or $a_n$ if necessary):

> *Claim*: If $\eta$ and $\tilde{\eta}$ both lead to well-defined values $S$ and $\tilde{S}$ for the above limit, then $S=\tilde{S}$.

(Or perhaps even "If any $\eta$ gives rise to a well-defined value $S$ for a series, then some particular stronger summation method M also ascribes $S$ to the series" in the same way that Norlund means force a generalization of the Abel sum to exist.)

This is a [cross-post from Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/460676/consistency-results-for-divergent-series-summed-with-smooth-cutoff-functions).